# PHP: Create new object of this class in class, is correct?

Tags: php, class, object, standards

Can I create new object inside class??

Is this correct and standard php?

```
<?php

class cronjob{
    private $k1, $m1;

    public function check_ready_to_moves(){

        $move_arr = array(
           array(
               'k1'=>'5',
               'm1'=>'8',
           ),
           array(
               'k1'=>'6',
               'm1'=>'23',
           ),
        ); //this parameters are expamle. in fact read from DB


        foreach($move_arr as $move){
            $cron = new cronjob(); // Is this Correct??
            $cron->set_package_param($move['k1'], $move['m1'])
                 ->move_to_FTP();
        }

    }

    public function set_package_param($k1, $m1){
        $this->k1 = $k1;
        $this->m1 = $m1;
        return $this;
    }

    private function move_to_FTP(){
        $this->k1;
        $this->m1; //use these in function .....


    }

    private function integration_db(){
        $this->k1;
        $this->m1; //use these in function .....

    }
}

?>
```

Insted of

```
        foreach($move_arr as $move){
            $cron = new cronjob(); // Is this Correct??
            $cron->set_package_param($move['k1'], $move['m1'])
                 ->move_to_FTP();
        }
```

Do you have better code suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean "correct"? Did you try it? Did it work? Did something happen other than what you expected?

Comment: it's ok. You could also do `new static()` so you don't have to update the class name in two places if it changes

Comment: @onetrickpony: Better make that `new self()`. No sense in bringing LSB into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using $this

like so:

```
foreach($move_arr as $move){
        // get rid of this line  --- $cron = new cronjob(); // Is this Correct??
        $this->set_package_param($move['k1'], $move['m1']) 
             ->move_apk_to_FTP();
    }
```